# I cant change the color of a toast in android

Tags: java, android

```
Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "color" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        View v = toast.getView();
        v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.toast);
        toast.show();
```

```
when I click the button that should do this the whole app crashes

I checked everything I don't know what is the problem of my android studio with this code

I tried everything but I don't know what is the problem 

it's funny that I couldn't find anyone else on the internet with the same problem

please help
```

Comment: It was possible to use custom Toast but since Android 11 is not possible to use it.  The Google recommendation is to use snackbar.

Answer (score 3):

You're getting crash because Apps targeting Android 11 `toast.getView()` method returns null when you access it to maintain a good user experience.

If you want to change the background, you have to use a custom layout.

The following snippet contains a customized layout `custom_toast.xml` for a toast notification:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/custom_toast_container"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:padding="8dp"
              android:background="#DAAA"
              >
    <ImageView android:src="@drawable/droid"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
               />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/text"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:textColor="#FFF"
              />
</LinearLayout>
```

And then use it as follows:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_toast,
                (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.custom_toast_container));

TextView text = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.text);
text.setText("This is a custom toast");

Toast toast = new Toast(getApplicationContext());
toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL, 0, 0);
toast.setDuration(Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
toast.setView(layout);
toast.show();
```

Comment: yes, these changes were introduced for API 11 or above.

Answer (score 0):

Create New Class

```
    public class WhiteCustomToast {
    public static void Make(Context context, String message) {
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.R) {
            View view = toast.getView();
            view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.white_cutom_bg);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.message);
            //text.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
            text.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFFFF"));
            text.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);
            text.setTypeface(Utilities.Ubuntu_Regular);
            text.setTextSize(14f);
        }
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

And Used in Main Class or Every Where

```
WhiteCustomToast.Make(context, "Checking");
```